# How to replace the server url filename with another name in filepond control

Tags: javascript, angular, filepond

Filepond gets the filename to display from the source url of filename provided.

The problem I have is that the fileserver (s3) files are saved with a UUID while the user filename provided on upload is stored in DB.

How to to replace the UUID filename from fileserver with the value stored in the database?

I have the filename in `m.filename` which is avialable during the init functon call:

```
      ApiService.ApiDataExtractor(this._a.getMedia({ offset: this.offset, limit: this.limit })).subscribe(
        r => {
          if (r) {
            this.pondFiles = r.map(m => {
              return {
                source: m.url_thumb,
                options: {
                  type: "local",
                },
              }
            });
          }
        }
      );
    }
```

I have tried:

Adding filedata to the FilePondOptions["files"] array but this is for mocking only and will not call the load() function in the instance if present.

Variously trying to chnagethe response and blob object in a custom load function.